Difficulty in understanding the proof of Theorem 2, section 40 of 'Introduction to Hilbert spaces and theory of spectral multiplicity' by Halmos
Suppose we are given a measurable space $(X, \Omega)$ where $\Omega$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$ and a Hilbert space $H$. Let $E: \Omega \rightarrow B(H)$ be the spectral measure on $\Omega$ where image of $E$ is a projection operator. $E$ satisfies countable additivity and $E(X)=I$. Corresponding to $E$, we define a complex measure  for every pair $(x,y)$ of vectors in $H$ as  $\mu_{x,y}(M)=\left<E(M)x,y\right>$.
For a given $E$ and a bounded measurable complex valued function $f$ (measurable with respect to $\Omega$), there exists a unique operator $A \in B(H)$ defined as $\left<Ax,y\right>=\int{f d{\mu_{x,y}}}$. In notation we write $A=\int{f dE}$. This integral distributes over addition, multiplication and  scalar multiplication of integrand, i.e. $\int{(f+g) dE}=\int{f dE}+ \int{g dE}$ and so on.  Also, $\int{\overline{f} dE}=({\int{f dE}})^*$
This is the background. Statement of the theorem says the following. Let $(\mathbb{C}, \Omega)$ be a measurable space where $\Omega$ is the $\sigma$ algebra of Borel subsets of $\mathbb{C}$. Let $E$ be a spectral measure.  If $B \in B(H)$ is such that it commutes with $\int{I dE}$ and $\int{\overline{I} dE}$ (Since $X=\mathbb{C}$ here, we can talk of I (identity function)), then $B$ commutes with $E(M)$ for every $M \in \Omega$.
In the proof, the following has been done. Let $A=\int{I dE}$. Given that $B$ commutes with $A$ and $A^*$. Let $A_r=\dfrac{A+A^*}{2}$ and $A_{i}=\dfrac{A-A^*}{2}$. Then using distributive properties of spectral integrals, we have, $B$ commutes with $A_r=\int{{I_r} dE}$ and $A_i=\int{{I_i} dE}$ where $I_r(z)=Re(z)$ and $I_i(z)=Im(z)$. Till here it is fine.
Then they say hence $B$ commutes with all spectral operators where integrand is  real valued polynomial in $I_r$ and $I_i$ and hence it commutes with $E(M)$. The problem is that the commutativity does hold for polynomial functions in $I_r$ and $I_i$ in which constant term is absent. From here it is not evident that it holds for constant polynomials. Once it works for constant polynomials then the proof follows.
I tried with certain special polynomials so that constant comes into picture but then it doesnot solve the problem. For example if we consider ${A_r}^2-A_r$. We have $B({A_r}^2-A_r)=({A_r}^2-A_r)B$ which gives $BA_r(A_r-E(M))=(A_r-E(M))A_rB$ (as $\int_M{}DE=E(M)$). Since $B$ commutes with $A_r$ and $A_r$ commutes with $E(M)$, we have $A_rBE(M)=A_rE(M)B$. From here, how to get rid of $A_r$, I am not following. Infact surjectivity of $A_r$ can also bring the claim (transferring the content to complex measure) but then we don't know about the behaviour of these spectral operators.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
